# Filter EC2 based on tag while sending EC2 Instance State-change Notification through SNS using Cloudwatch event rule

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch-events

I am trying to configure AWS Event rule using event pattern. Bye default the code is

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.ec2"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "EC2 Instance State-change Notification"
  ]
}
```

I want to filter the EC2 based on tag lets say all of my EC2 has unique AppID attached i.e.20567. Reason I want to filter it because other teams have EC2's under same AWS account and I want to configure SNS only for the instances that belongs to me based on tag 'App ID'

Target I have selected SNS topic and using input formatter with value

```
{"instance":"$.detail.instance-id","state":"$.detail.state","time":"$.time","region":"$.region","account":"$.account"}
```

Any suggestion where can I pass tag key value to filter my EC2 Instances.

Answer (score 0):

I can only speak for Cloudwatch Events (now called as EventBridge). We do not get tag information from EC2 prior to rule-matching. A sample EC2 event is shown at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/event-types.html#ec2-event-type

```json
{
   "id":"7bf73129-1428-4cd3-a780-95db273d1602",
   "detail-type":"EC2 Instance State-change Notification",
   "source":"aws.ec2",
   "account":"123456789012",
   "time":"2015-11-11T21:29:54Z",
   "region":"us-east-1",
   "resources":[
      "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789012:instance/i-abcd1111"
   ],
   "detail":{
      "instance-id":"i-abcd1111",
      "state":"pending"
   }
}
```

So you best course of action would be to fetch the tags for a resource and filter out the events after reading.